# Swift Button Grayed Out

Tags: swift

I am comparing two numbers and the counter goes up by 1 if two numbers are not equal.
However, the labels does not update and the start button becomes grayed out. The button is grayed out until those two numbers became equal.

```
    import UIKit

enum modes {
case start
case cancel
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var mode: modes = modes.start
    var num1: Int = 0
    var num2: Int = 1
    var count: Int = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var start: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func startClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (mode == modes.start) {
            mode = modes.cancel
            start.title = "cancel"
            checkNums()
        } else if (mode == modes.cancel) {
            mode = modes.start
            start.title = "start"
            num1 = 0
            num2 = 1
        }
    }

func checkNums() {
    while (num1 != num2) {
        let temp: UInt32 = 100000
        num1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(temp))
        num2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(temp))
        print("\(num1) and \(num2)")
        update()
    }

    func update() {
        count += 1
        label.text = "\(num1) and \(num2)"
        countLabel.text = "\(count)"
    }
}
```

Please help!
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried enabled attribute of the button? e.g.: myButton.enabled = false will make it disabled.

Comment: @Array Yes, but the problem is that the program is not updating while It compares two values. It update only the last result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [UICountingLabel](http://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel) in place of UILabel

Comment: Hi, I updated checkNums(). I changed it right before I wrote here.

Comment: let temp: UInt32 = 100000
        num1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(temp))
        num2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(temp))

These lines of code should be in viewDidLoad()

Comment: As every time it will generate a new random number. And I think your goal is just to take two random numbers and increment counter until these two becomes equal.

Comment: Or your goal is to find in how many attempts these two random numbers become equal ?

Comment: @AshishVerma I would like to see two numbers updating on the label, but it only shows the last result.

Comment: Then try third-party library UICounringLabel in place of UILabel
https://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel

Comment: @AshishVerma Thank you!

Comment: Verman I am sorry. I was new so I did not know how to choose the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anywhere where you are updating the values of num1 and num2. Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but I would guess that you should be setting new values for the two numbers in your update function?

Comment: I get two random numbers and then compared but I set the new values before I wrote it here. I thought that would be more clear. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Either way, your values need to change inside the update function or your app will be stuck there forever.

Comment: I just correct them, but I still have the problem. It updates the label for the only last result.

Comment: You'll only ever see the last result because the app will race through the steps very quickly only stopping when it gets to a conclusion, so that's all you see. If you want to see every step then you need to add something to slow things down, like triggering each update with a timer.